# Android studio does not automatically launch the application

Tags: java, android

When I run my application from Android studio, the application is installed on the phone but it does not launching automatically.

Comment: Maybe it is already launched before and minimized/hidden.

Comment: @MikheilZhghenti No. Because the same thing happens when I install it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was missing setting: `Launch`

```
Edit configurations -> [main module] -> General -> Launch options -> Launch -> Default activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it manually?
If you have and it's running, sometimes it just happens, try to maybe restart android studio / your phone.
If when you manually running the app it won't run, it means you are getting an exception very early during the startup session and you'll need to debug it.

Comment: The same thing happens when I start a new and empty android studio project. I don't get an early error. I have this situation in all applications.

Comment: Did you try closing and opening android studio + restarting your android device?

Comment: Yes i did. Its not about device.

Answer (score 0):

Before launching the app, minimize the app(press home button) or exit the app from device/emulator. Then the app will auto launch.

Comment: When i install first time it happens again.

Comment: Sometimes, for instance, if you changed your package,  Android does not recognize the launcher activity, unless there has been a clean and build. Trying cleaning your code, and relaunch the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused this problem. However, when I uninstall the android studio and reinstall it, the problem was resolved.